# Python reading date from excel throws error

Tags: python

I am trying to read date from excel file using xlrd module. Below is my code for this :

```
# Variables
myfile = '/home/mobaxterm/.git/Operation_Documentation/docs/Servicing Portal User &  Certificate Inventory.xlsx'
mydate = 'Expiration Date'
row_head = 0

# Import required modules
import xlrd
import datetime


today = datetime.date.today()
book = xlrd.open_workbook(myfile)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
        print xlrd.cellname(row_head,col_index),"-",
        print sheet.cell(row_head,col_index).value
        if sheet.cell(row_head,col_index).value == mydate:
                for raw_index in range(sheet.nrows):
                        expire = sheet.cell(raw_index,col_index).value
                        print expire
                        expire_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(expire, book.datemode))    
                        print 'datetime: %s' %  expire_date
                break
```

While running the code i am getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cert_monitor.py", line 31, in <module>
    expire_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(expire, book.datemode))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xlrd/xldate.py", line 61, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Expiration Date'
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue here?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you parsing the column header as an date?

Comment: Output types of arguments for xlrd.xldate_as_tuple: print type( expire ), print type( book.datemode ); then view a documentation for the function: probably one of the parameters has a wrong type.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing the code from line 31?  `mydate` is the only name with the value `'Expiration Date'` and the line that uses it does not look like it is the problem.  You may need to show a simplified example of the file that shows the problem.

Comment: @dansalmo, this string is probably the header in the xls file.

Comment: Problematic part in the code is `expire_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(expire, book.datemode))    
                        print 'datetime: %s' %  expire_date` if i remove that part code is working till that point. So when i try to convert excel column data (float) to date format at that time it is throwing the error.

Comment: BTW, it's `row_index`, not `raw_index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should only skip the header:

```
for raw_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    ...
```

You are checking that `sheet.cell(row_head,col_index).value == mydate`, and then you want to iterate over the rows, but you should skip `row_head` first - it is `==mydate`, which is not a date but a simple 'Expiration Date' string.

Comment: Its date conversion of excel data which is causing problem. Other code is working absolutely fine.

Comment: @user2501825 have you tried my solution? your *excel data* you are trying to convert to date is not really a date. it is the column header.

Comment: Yeah after making that change i was able to print first date but still throws the same error and quits.`python cert_monitor.py
A1 - Server Name
B1 - Task
C1 - Username
D1 - Purpose
E1 - Password Expiration
F1 - Expiration Date
41450.0
datetime: 2013-06-25 00:00:00

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cert_monitor.py", line 31, in <module>
    expire_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(expire, book.datemode))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xlrd/xldate.py", line 61, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
`

Comment: I think you have empty rows there.

Comment: You are awesome. After first raw two raws are empty. I guess i have to put logic to ignore empty raws. Thanks for pointing that out. Appreciate your time.